# I have a code that separates data into different worksheets, now I want to try include graphs in the new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm new to VBA and was trying to make a VBA project that will loop through a table containing data of trucks, to generate reports for each of them. Currently I have a code that will separate the data in the table to different worksheets based on individual trucks, and I have been trying to edit the code so that the new worksheets with separated data will also contain a graph for it.

My current code looks like this:

```vb
Sub IndividualReports()

Dim SplitFld As Range 'the column the end user will select to base the split on
Dim Hdgs As Range 'the headings needed on each worksheet
Dim SplitItem As Range 'the current value in the column that has been selected
Dim NewWs As Worksheet 'a new worksheet as required
Dim ws As Worksheet 'worksheets in the current workbook
Dim WsExists As Boolean 'TRUE or FALSE: does a worksheet already exist for the SplitItem?
Dim SplitWs As Worksheet 'The active worksheet
Set SplitWs = ActiveSheet
Dim Report As ChartObject
Dim i As Range
Dim j As Range
Set i = Range("C2").End(xlDown)
Set j = Range("C2").End(xlToRight)
    Dim graphRange As Range
    
On Error GoTo SplitFldError 'if the user cancels the SplitFld inputbox exit sub
'ask user to select the column to base the split on and store that range in the SplitFld variable
Set SplitFld = Application.InputBox _
(Prompt:="Select the column you want to split your data by", _
Title:="Column", Type:=8)

On Error GoTo HdgsError 'if the user cancels the Hdgs inputbox exit sub
'ask the user to select the column headings and store that range in the Hdgs variable
Set Hdgs = Application.InputBox _
(Prompt:="Select the headings you want to appear on each worksheet", _
Title:="Headings", Type:=8)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turning off screen updating makes the code run faster

For Each SplitItem In SplitFld 'for each value in the column the user has selected
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = SplitItem Then 'check whether a worksheet already exists for that value
            WsExists = True ' and store TRUE or FALSE in the WsExists variable
            Exit For
        Else
            WsExists = False
        End If
    Next ws
    
    
    If WsExists Then 'if WsExists = TRUE, (if the worksheet does already exist)
    
        'copy the record to the next available row in that worksheet
        Range(SplitItem.End(xlToLeft), SplitItem.End(xlToLeft).End(xlToRight)).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets(SplitItem.Value).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        SetReport = Worksheets(SplitItem.Value).ChartObjects.Add(Worksheets(SplitItem.Value))
     With Report
    .SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range(i, j)
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""pH"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets(SplitItem.Value).Range("E2").End(Down)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""RA"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets(SplitItem.Value).Range("F2").End(Down)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = Worksheets(SplitItem.Value).Range("D2").End(Down)
    End With
    
        Else 'if WsExists = 'FALSE (if a worksheet doesn't yet exist)
        
        'Create a new worksheet and place it to the right of other worksheets in the workbook
        Set NewWs = Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        'Name the worksheet using the current value stored in the SplitItem variable
        NewWs.Name = SplitItem
        
        'Copy the headings to the new worksheet
        Hdgs.Copy Destination:=NewWs.Range("A1")
        
        'Copy the record to the new worksheet
        Range(SplitItem.End(xlToLeft), SplitItem.End(xlToLeft).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=NewWs.Range("A2")
         Set graphRange = NewWs.Range("C2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)
         Set Report = NewWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=50, Height:=225)
         With Report.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=graphRange
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    Report.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""pH"""
    Report.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = NewWs.Range("D2").End(Down)
    Report.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""RA"""
    Report.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = NewWs.Range("E2").End(Down)
    Report.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = NewWs.Range("C2").End(Down)
    End With
    End If

Next SplitItem


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'autofit columns in each worksheet

    ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

Next ws

'turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

SplitFldError:
Exit Sub

HdgsError:
Exit Sub
    
End Sub
```

But for some reason while the code would run, it will stop at the first set of data and the graph fails to register the data source. I couldn't figure out how to edit my code so I would really appreciate it if someone could provide me some insights on it. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `Set Report = ... ` a space is missing after `Set`. btw, `SplitItem.End(xlToLeft).End(xlToRight)` can be simplified as `SplitItem.End(xlToRight)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. I edited the code as you suggested but the problem still persists.

Comment: Please edit your post to post the latest code.